# Eclipse Plugin : ArrayOutOfBoundError when trying to run the plugin through terminal, works fine in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have made an Eclipse plugin, in Application.java, I am trying to access the projects in the workspace that I have mentioned in the configuration while running the plugin. 
I have created a headless plugin by exporting the plugin as an Eclipse Application, and trying to run that from the terminal.
These are the arguments that I have given to the run it from the terminal -> `./eclipse -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=512m -application eclipse.commandline.application -data __workspace-path__  -nosplash -console -consoleLog`

The workspace is not being recognised from the terminal. The plugin is not able to find any projects in the workspace. When I run the plugin in Eclipse by giving the appropriate run configurations, it is working perfectly fine.
I am making the project in Ubuntu14.04 on Eclipse Neon.

```java
public Object start(IApplicationContext arg0) throws Exception {
  IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
    IPath rootPath = root.getLocation();
    String workspacePath = rootPath.toOSString();
    root = workspace.getRoot();
    rootPath = root.getLocation();
    File rootFile = rootPath.toFile();
    File[] contents = rootFile.listFiles();
    IProject project = root.getProjects()[0]; // Error in this line.
}
```

**Project structure** 
**Workspace** 
       -- **trunk**

Comment: What do you mean by 'recognised from the terminal'? What exactly are you doing? Eclipse plugins can only run inside Eclipse.

Comment: You need to show us a minimal version of your `IApplication` code. Have you checked that the Eclipse has got the correct workspace location?

Comment: added the code, it is very basic code where I am just trying to access the workspace from the plugin. Works fine in Eclipse. Not when I export it as a headless plugin. The workspace location that I am specifying is correct at both the locations.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work provided the workspace path is correct.

Comment: Try opening Eclipse itself on that given workspace folder and then opening the 'Navigator' view to see if you can see any projects.

Comment: How was this workspace initially created?

Comment: this workspace was created programmatically, and projects were added.

Comment: Details matter. Normally, plug-ins don't "create" the workspace, the `org.eclipse.core.resources` handles that itself. An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with a fixed index of 0 tells me you actually have *no* projects in this workspace, so either the workspace or the projects you think are in there are not. So, again, how was this workspace created?